# How to store SQL injection attacks in DB

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I'll start by that I know how to prevent SQL injection. That is not the problem I'm faced with.

I manage 50+ websites and they get a ton of spam and injection attacks a day between them. Currently, I have it set so that I get an email sent to me whenever that happens. So the detection and stopping are working.

However, it clutters my mailbox right now and isn't very easy to filter through to see the real ones from the regular 'xxx' spam.

We have a central online management application that we use for several other things, among which is an account of every website we manage. What I'd like to do is show the attacks in that system. How do I safely send and store (in DB or file or whatever) possibly harmful text and then proceed to show it in that system?

I've hit a roadblock right there. All I can find on harmful SQL injection text is how to stop and prevent it, not how to actually store it (I'm just that crazy). My first thought was to just store in a text file on the server, but that doesn't seem like a decent option to me for some reason. I'd have to load tons of files whenever I want to look at the full list of attacks.

I hope someone can help point me in the right direction. I'm using MySQL and PHP.

Comment: If you have as you say a method to email you the attacks, why not just create a new table and store those in there? Edit: Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqlnd-qc-get-normalized-query-trace-log.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php

Comment: Do the emails not contain all attack attempts?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Is it safe to do that though? The whole purpose of stopping SQL injection is to not get it into the DB right?

Comment: @user3783243 They do, but those emails are sent from the different websites. I'd like to centralize the attacks so I can get an overview at a quick glance and patch where needed.

Comment: It's safe to store a name like "O'Reilly" in a database, even though that can cause SQL injection if you don't handle it correctly. You either escape the quote, or else use query parameters. Use the same method to store any other type of content in a database. There's nothing dangerous about the content if you use good practices for using the strings in SQL statements (that is, use parameters, don't interpolate strings).

Comment: @Nahbyr the purpose of stopping SQL injection is to prevent a query from doing what it not supposed to do.

Comment: Change the email function to a prepared statement and you should be good to go.

Comment: Let me answer in a different way. I've seen scripts out there that will see if an input contains characters that could potentially cause a "lethal" injection. Now that has its pros but mostly cons. Here's one con; if a user chose a password that is considered as being a string for a lethal injection, what do you think will happen? *Wink!* That's where `password_verify()` comes into play. It takes that into account, and by not escaping passwords that could potentially break a valid password. If you're using a prepared statement and `password_hash()`, you're good to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose to store the injection is just for logging and analytical purpose, then i will suggest you to use a logging software, such as Graylog, which is free. It's more decent than either RDMS or file.

I have been using Graylog for storing application logs from multiple servers. There are PHP implementation to send logs to Graylog from PHP.

Comment: This looks promising. I'll have a look later today. I like it from the quick glance I've had. Thanks